# Checking for value already stored in associative array

Tags: associative-array, system-verilog

I want to tap a signal and enter into an associative array.Also,I need to make sure every time I am tapping a value,it should be different from what's already stored in the associative array.

```
 logic [31:0] addr[int]; 

    eg.if addr[0]=1
          addr[1]=2
          addr[2]=3
```

If the the next value is again 1,2 or 3.I should not assign it to my associative array and go to the next iteration.

Is it possible to accomplish using a associative array or any other type of array should be more convenient. If it's possible, can some please provide some logic on how to achieve it.

Let me know if something is unclear.Any help is greatly appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `find()` array locator method. And since you will adding one array element at a time in sequential index ordering, you should use a queue.

```
logic [31:0] adds[$];


if ( addr.find() with (item == value) == {} ) addr.push_back(value);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am getting an error :  Cannot mix packed and unpacked types in this operation.  I am getting the  value from haddr[31:0] and I changed (item=value} to (item==value) from the solution you provided.